# Syntax error: missing ';' before '*' with Item class

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm encountering these errors:

```
1>...\inventory.h(9): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '*'
1>...\inventory.h(9): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>...\inventory.h(9): error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
1>...\inventory.h(15): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>...\inventory.h(15): error C2143: syntax error: missing ',' before '&'
```

When trying to compile the following code.

Inventory.h

```
#pragma once
#include "Includes.h"

class Inventory
{
private:
    int inv_cap;
    int inv_nrOfItems;
    Item **inv_itemArr;
    void expand();
    void initialize(const int from);
public:
    Inventory();
    virtual ~Inventory();
    void addItem(const Item &inv_item);
    void removeItem(int index);

};
```

Includes.h

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>
#include "Functions.h"
#include "Character.h"
#include "Item.h"
#include "Inventory.h"

using namespace std;
```

Item.h

```
#pragma once
#include "Includes.h"

class Item
{
private:
    std::string i_name;
    int i_buyValue;
    int i_sellValue;


public:
    Item();
    virtual ~Item();

    inline void debugPrint() const
    {
        std::cout << i_name << std::endl;
    }


};
```

Based on the googling I've done, my problems seems to have to do with forward declaration, but I'm in the dark as how to fix it.

Comment: Circular include, I'd imagine. Not sure why you have an includes file like that. Only include what is actually needed.

Comment: Thanks ChrisMM! I have other source files that use the other files in the Includes.h, but the compiler didn't start throwing errors until I added the Inventory class. Hope that helps!

Comment: Try adding `class Item;` before the class declaration in `Inventory.h`.

Comment: Also, you can remove `Includes.h` from `Inventory.h` and `Item.h`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're coming from a higher-level language like C#, `#include` doesn't work the same as a `using`. `#include` essentially copies and pastes the entire file inline.

You can then see the problem of having `Item.h` include `Includes.h`  which then includes `Inventory.h`, but then when `Inventory.h` tries to include `Includes.h`, it's already been included so it skips it (because of the `#pragma once`) and `Item` still isn't defined yet. *In short, `class Inventory` ends up being defined above the `class Item`, but `class Inventory` expects the `Item` class to have already been defined.*

It'd be best to delete the `Includes.h` file completely and have `Inventory.h` specifically include `Item.h`.

Comment: Are you saying that `Item.h` Not include `Includes.h` as well as `Inventory.h`?

Comment: `Item still isn't defined yet` That is the case, indeed, but `Inventory` does not need the full definition of `Item` at that point since it's only using pointers and references to it. So it would be enough to [forward declare](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/553682/when-can-i-use-a-forward-declaration) `class Item;` before it is used in `inventory.h`, as noted in another comment.

Comment: Yep, this was exactly the problem! Attempting to forward declare class Item; only created more problems. Once I sorted out the various includes I was attempting to do, it had no problems at all. Thank you everyone for all of the helpful feedback!